Handling file upload into Saucelabs Project Vault drive and needs to overwrite if file already exists
I have one scenario in automation to use a file from Saucelabs Project Vault Drive and upload the updated data into same file. I'm using axios API to reach Saucelabs and I'm getting 200 when trying to upload a file but file info is not updated.
Below is the sample structure of URL:
'''
Https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/api/project/project-id/drive/files/file-id
'''
I'm able to access the file data through axios.get and also uploading also working as expected but not updating the file. I'm assuming like saucelabs ask for the confirmation to replace file if file already exist.
Any solution from any one will be very helpful.
